# How do you create a grammar?

Tags: formal-languages

What are the paths to create a grammar of a specified type?
For example, how do I define a type 3 grammar for the language of the strings on the alphabet {a,b} that contain an odd number of "a".

Comment: Your question is not precise enough. Do you start with a regular language, like in your example?

Comment: Hint: first find a grammar for strings with an odd number of "a"s and no "b"s. Then modify that grammar to allow arbitrary (possibly empty) strings of "b"s to appear anywhere in a string. If you are asking for a general method for solving this kind of problem, I don't know of one.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin my book doesn't say how do I build a grammar, it says what the grammar consists of, but my question is how do I build the production rules?

Comment: @FBIT: Um .. you just write them down? You don't have to follow any particular procedure for coming up with the grammar, as long as the result you get works (and you can prove it works).

Answer (score 2):

As a different approach from Stefan's, you could also (1) notice that your language is regular, (2) draw a DFA for it:

[image: DFA]

and (3) write out the corresponding regular grammar. This produces:

$$ \begin{align} S & \to bS \mid aT \\ T & \to bT \mid aS \mid {\varepsilon}\end{align} $$

Comment: I've added a hand-drawn picture of the DFA that you probably thought of. I hope you don't mind. (If someone else could be bothered to actually render a DFA, that would be ideal.)

Comment: @FBIT This is actually the generic solution to get a regular grammar for a given regular language. It works for any given regular language.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has a nice article on [Formal grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar).

And here is a type $3$ grammar to deal with your example:

$S \to a$

$S \to bS$

$S \to Sb$

$S \to aSa$

$S \to Saa$

$S \to aaS$

An easy proof by induction on the number of applied rules shows that only strings with an odd number of $a$'s can be constructed. On the other hand, every such string is obtainable: Let $x$ be a counterexample of minimal length. By the rule $S \mapsto bS$, the leftmost character of $x$ must be $a$. By $S \mapsto Sb$ the last character of $x$ must be $a$. Write $x = aya$. Then $y$ has an odd number of $a$'s and, by the minimality of $x$, can hence be constructed. But then $S \mapsto aSa$ witnessed that $x$ can be constructed as well. Contradiction!

---

Note that this proof also shows that the rules $S \mapsto Saa$ and $S \mapsto aaS$ are not actually required. Something that I didn't notice until I went through the motions.

Comment: I don't need a solution, I just need to know how do I define a grammar whit its production rules.

Comment: In that case, Wikipedia has a nice article on [Formal grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar).

Comment: $S\to Saaa$ does not look to me like a rule that even preserves the parity of the number of $a$s in the string. (And neither does your other production).

Comment: @HenningMakholm You're right, of course. My mind decided to change the problem to "the number of $a$'s is a multiple of $3$". I'll edit it.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I think I fixed it.

Comment: It seems to work now, but your own argument here shows that you don't need the Saa and aaS rules.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I just realized that myself as you can see from my edit. But thanks :-)

Comment: How'd you create the rules?

Comment: @FBIT The idea behind the grammar above is as follows: Start with the non-terminal $S$. After each step there is exactly one non-terminal $S$ in our string or the only non-terminal $S$ has been replaced with $a$. If there is a non-terminal left in our string, the number of $a$'s in that string is even. This will force the number of $a$'s to be odd, once there is no non-terminal left.

Comment: @FBIT If your question is how one creates such a grammar in general -- for a given language. Well, that's a difficult question (it's actually difficult in a precise, formal sense). But for languages that one encounters in a mathematician's (student's) everyday life, there is usually a simple idea that one needs to discovere -- however our brains manage to do that.

Comment: okay thank you, so there's a way to name the non-terminal symbols, not considering S that is a must, or I can choose whatever symbol I want?

Comment: @FBIT You can choose whatever symbol you want but it's standard to denote non-terminal symbols with capital characters.